# How can I troubleshoot MariaDB crash

Tags: mariadb

MariaDB has crashed several times in the last week.

The following is an excerpt from the log immediately following the last crash.

How can I troubleshoot this to hopefully avoid future crashes?

I included two lines from about two hours before the crash as they might be relevant. I do not know why these name resolution errors are appearing.

They seem to be hack attempts, as the listed IP address is in Hong Kong.

```
2018-03-08 17:59:36 140300723444480 [Warning] IP address '164.52.6.148' could not be resolved: Temporary failure in name resolution
2018-03-08 17:59:36 140300723444480 [Warning] IP address '164.52.6.148' could not be resolved: Temporary failure in name resolution
180308 19:10:46 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.1.16-MariaDB
key_buffer_size=134217728
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=21
max_threads=153
thread_count=3
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 467113 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0x7f9a297fa008
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0x7f9a4eccf140 thread_stack 0x48400
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2b)[0x7f9a52d35aab]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x475)[0x7f9a52892ef5]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf7e0)[0x7f9a51e987e0]
/lib64/libresolv.so.2(__libc_res_nquery+0x1e8)[0x7f9a4eef8858]
/lib64/libresolv.so.2(+0x8dd0)[0x7f9a4eef8dd0]
/lib64/libresolv.so.2(__libc_res_nsearch+0x1e8)[0x7f9a4eef98f8]
/lib64/libnss_dns.so.2(_nss_dns_gethostbyname4_r+0xf7)[0x7f9a19dec7d7]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0xcff03)[0x7f9a5035bf03]
/lib64/libc.so.6(getaddrinfo+0x150)[0x7f9a5035ef30]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z14ip_to_hostnameP16sockaddr_storagePKcPPcPj+0x48d)[0x7f9a5289f5ad]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x51dbf8)[0x7f9a527e5bf8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16login_connectionP3THD+0x45)[0x7f9a527e6dc5]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z22thd_prepare_connectionP3THD+0x19)[0x7f9a527e7579]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24do_handle_one_connectionP3THD+0x158)[0x7f9a527e7728]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_one_connection+0x47)[0x7f9a527e78a7]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7aa1)[0x7f9a51e90aa1]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f9a50374aad]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0x0): is an invalid pointer
Connection ID (thread ID): 933190
Status: NOT_KILLED

Optimizer switch: index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,index_merge_sort_intersection=off,engine_condition_pushdown=off,index_condition_pushdown=on,derived_merge=on,derived_with_keys=on,firstmatch=on,loosescan=on,materialization=on,in_to_exists=on,semijoin=on,partial_match_rowid_merge=on,partial_match_table_scan=on,subquery_cache=on,mrr=off,mrr_cost_based=off,mrr_sort_keys=off,outer_join_with_cache=on,semijoin_with_cache=on,join_cache_incremental=on,join_cache_hashed=on,join_cache_bka=on,optimize_join_buffer_size=off,table_elimination=on,extended_keys=on,exists_to_in=on,orderby_uses_equalities=off

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.

We think the query pointer is invalid, but we will try to print it anyway. 
Query:
```

Comment: Nope, address resolution shouldn't trigger a landmine here. Anyway generic data is rather useful to report to MySQL/Maria team, I guess someone need to know a lot about internals to be able to help here.
Take the QA way - fire up full log, more data and try to locate the query that triggers this. Also page through the MariaDB documentation and clean up you configuration file. I mean it! A lot of stuff sitting there for more then two years might be a horrible wrong choice!

Comment: Looks like a hardware problem. Test and replace any defective hardware.